# creating strings in R containing special/dedicated characters

Tags: r, string, concatenation, special-characters

I am trying to join strings containing dedicated characters, and obviously it gives me errors. Here's to illustrate:

```
v <- c(1:3)
FILE = '\\main.folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\file01.txt'
```

From there, I'd like to have an output that looks like this:

```
[1] "FILE = '\\main.folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\file1.txt'"
[2] "FILE = '\\main.folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\file2.txt'"
[3] "FILE = '\\main.folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\file3.txt'"
```

Here's my code: `str_c("FILE = '\\main.folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\file", v, ".txt'")`
Apparently, it's the backslash (and I'm guessing `'` too) that's causing the error. What's the workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: Your FILE is giving errors

Comment: @akrun I tried this `str_c("FILE = '", v)` and it's doing just fine.

Comment: Can you please check my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("FILE = '\\main.folder\\subfolder1\\subfolder2\\file%d.txt'", v)  
#[1] "FILE = '\\main.folder\\subfolder1\\subfolder2\\file1.txt'" "FILE = '\\main.folder\\subfolder1\\subfolder2\\file2.txt'"
#[3] "FILE = '\\main.folder\\subfolder1\\subfolder2\\file3.txt'"
```

#### data

```
v <- 1:3
```

Comment: it worked but what does `%d` do? in this particular case?

Comment: @mand3rd it is to specify that the element to be interpolated is digit

Comment: I see. The reason I asked is because it is still giving me errors when I applied it in my real data. I realized that my file path has `\data` part in it...

Comment: @mand3rd with single backslash it is giving errors on my console

Comment: oh yeah, that's right. it has to be a double backlash. I wonder though if the double backlash will give me some problems later on. but thanks!

Comment: it is just for escaping.  You can check with `nchar` or with `cat`, it is just a single backslash

Comment: oh yes, I ran my program with the double backlash and it worked! you've been very helpful. thanks!

Comment: For "future" reference: In `R-devel`, and hence the upcoming release, you have a new quote for raw character constants `r"{}"` that lets you write this as `stringr::str_c(r"{FILE = '\\main.folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\file}", v, ".txt")`.

Comment: @user12728748 in that, where is the notation to specify the location for 'v' interpolation.  Is it a typo?

Comment: @akrun - I basically did a paste job, not a substitution of the original FILE, like you did, it seems (with one typo - forgetting the final single quote). I suppose one could use the `FILE` variable directly like so: `v=1:3; FILE = r"{\\main.folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\file01.txt'}"; sprintf("FILE = `%s%d.txt'", sub("(.)(d+.txt)", "\\1", FILE), v)`